# yii2 how to add additional attributes to dropDownList() elements?

Tags: drop-down-menu, yii2

The question is simple. I want to add different data-attributes to each selection option so that Bootstrap will load different data according to which option was selected.

How should I go with it? Adding options to field()->dropDownList() will only add the options to list elements container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with options

```
 echo $form->field($model, 'name')->dropDownList( $listData,
                                ['options'=>['class' => 'yourClass', 
                                 'style' => 'yourStyle', 
                                  'yourAtt'=> 'yourattribute']]);
```

or try

```
echo $form->field($model, 'name')->dropDownList( $listData,
                                ['data-target'=> 'yourValue',
                                 'data-toggle' => ' your2value']);
```

for items you can use

```
echo $form->field($model, 'name')->dropDownList( $listData,
                                ['options'=>[
                                   'value1' => ['data-target' => 'yourAtt']]);,
```

Comment: What kind of attributes you want to add? show a sample

Comment: I want to add data-target and data-toggle attributes to trigger various Bootstrap events. But even simple class nor style attributes won't render.

Comment: Yes, but as I stated, my goal is to assign these values for every dropdown list element. This solution assigns these values to <select>.

I want it to be like:
`<select id="article" class="form-control"  name="Articles[article_type]">
    <option value="1" data-target="news">News</option>
    <option value="2" data-target="blog">Blog</option>
    <option value="3" data-target="gossip">Gossip</option>
</select>`

Comment: Yeah, I ended up with the same solution myself also. But thank you a lot!

Comment: That's not a complete answer.

Comment: i'll try also but data attribute is come in select option , i need in option data attribute

Comment: @ChiragPipariya  Your comment is not clear to me  .., evntually post a question properly described ..

Answer (score 8):

I got the result please try this one may be solve problem i got batter solution

```
$listOption           = [
                                [156] => 'Option1',
                                [157] => 'Option2',
                                [158] => 'Option3',
                                [162] => 'Option4'
                            ];


$optionDataAttributes = [
                                [156] => [
                                    ['data-width']  => 10,
                                    ['data-height'] => 10
                                ],
                                [157] => [
                                    ['data-width']  => 11,
                                    ['data-height'] => 11
                                ],
                                [158] => [
                                    ['data-width']  => 12,
                                    ['data-height'] => 12
                                ],
                                [162] => [
                                    ['data-width']  => 13,
                                    ['data-height'] => 13
                                ],
                            ];



echo $form->field($model, 'field_name')->dropDownList($listOption , 
    [ 
    'options' => $optionDataAttributes, 
    'prompt' => 'Select Custom Package', 
    'class' => 'form-control input-sm', 
    'id' => 'package_select_id'
    ])->label(false);
```